# hillshade issue with rayshader ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rayshader

Based on the code and data (obtained from `rayshader` tutorial website) provided in the post, I am getting the error shown below.

What might be causing it and how can it be fixed?

Error:

```
Error in hillshade[, , 1] * scales::rescale(shadowmap, c(max_darken, 1)) : 
  non-conformable arrays
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(viridis)
library(rayshader)

measles = read_csv("https://tylermw.com/data/measles_country_2011_2019.csv")
melt_measles = reshape2::melt(measles, id.vars = c("Year", "Country", "Region", "ISO3"))
melt_measles$Month = melt_measles$variable
melt_measles$cases = melt_measles$value

# Plot
melt_measles %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarize(totalcases = sum(cases,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(totalcases = ifelse(Year == 2019 & !(Month %in% c("January","February","March")), NA, totalcases)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=Year, y=Month, fill=totalcases,color=totalcases),size=1,color="black") + 
  scale_x_continuous("Year", expand=c(0,0), breaks = seq(2011,2019,1)) +
  scale_y_discrete("Month", expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis("Total\nCases") +
  ggtitle("Reported Worldwide Measles Cases") +
  labs(caption = "Data Source: WHO") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        title = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"),
        panel.border= element_rect(size=2,color="black",fill=NA)) -> 
measles_gg

plot_gg(measles_gg, multicore = TRUE, width = 6, height = 5.5, scale = 300, 
background = "#afceff",shadowcolor = "#3a4f70")
```

Comment: This is a known issue <https://github.com/tylermorganwall/rayshader/issues/176> I guess you have done some updates?!

Comment: `devtools::install_github("tylermorganwall/rayshader")` fixed it :)

Comment: Exactly. Took me so long to get it installed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue <github.com/tylermorganwall/rayshader/issues/176>

I tested with `remotes::install_github("tylermorganwall/rayshader")`

[image]